# Which chords can be played simultaneously?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, terminology

For example, my instrumental's chord progression = **Dm**, F, **C**, Bb

Which chords can be played at the same time as Dm and C and still sound "good"? Is there some sort of terminology for chords like this?

Comment: Do you mean "in a sequence", rather than literally at the same time?

Comment: I don't think you're asking what you want to/think you're asking (not just this specific question, your questions in general often seem a little confused), you should probably read some intro-to-theory stuff. http://openmusictheory.com/contents.html if you like reading, I guess 12Tone's building blocks video series is okay if you'd prefer videos.

Comment: Not in sequence at the same time

Comment: Don't take anyone's word for it: try it out. You may well disagree with any answers. That won't make you or them right or wrong, though.

Comment: @James - I was just checking because thinking of music in terms of two chords being played at the same time is an unusual way of thinking about harmony. Of course there's nothing wrong with thinking in unusual ways, but usually the current chord at any time in a song is a name for all the notes that are currently playing - i.e. people normally want to think of one chord name that refers to all those notes.

Comment: Do you want a chord that can be played at the same time as **both the Dm chord and the C chord being played simultaneously**? That's my current understanding of your question.

Comment: Are you asking what chords could form a "nice sounding" polychord with the Dm11 chord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general terms for whether two things -- notes or chords -- sound good together are "consonance" (good) and "dissonance" (bad).

Since at root this is a question of aesthetics, there's no rule. If you want to follow 19th century musical aesthetics, then any note (let alone chord) you add to one of those basic triads is dissonant, and therefore "bad" in the sense I think is meant by the question. (More accurately, dissonant pitches require special handling to resolve them to a consonance.)

On the other hand, contemporary music is much more tolerant of the "sounds formerly known as dissonances". For example, in most cases, adding a seventh or ninth to a chord would be considered consonant for most purposes.

In the particular progression `Dm F C Bb`, all of the chords are native to the key of F major (or D minor), so for the most part, you could add any chord that also belongs to F major, and it would still sound okay in the larger context.

In general, you may want to stay away from a perfect fourth above the root of a major chord. Thus, F major on top of C major may sound odd. But aside from that loose restriction, all you're really doing is adding extensions onto the existing progression.

For example (and staying within F major):

```
F    over Dm = Dm7
Gm   over Dm = Dm13(omit 7)
Am   over Dm = Dm9
Bb   over Dm = Dm(b6)
C    over Dm = Dm11
Dm   over Dm = Dm
Edim over Dm = Dm7b13
```

Comment: I'd add that the aspects of "consonance" and "dissonance" are also based on the context of their meaning. Even while using diatonic chords, the dimished fifth created on the leading note triad is considered dissonant without adding any other note to it. And if we want to go even further, even *any* triad could be considered dissonant, considering perfect consonances. But, then again, some would argue that even perfect fourths and fifths are dissonant using the tempered system ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several useful substitutions for a chord that can be used to replace the cord or extend the chord.  When you do this you are creating a new chord and one term that applies is poly chord.  Although your post is NOT guitar specific I'd say one of the best sources of info on poly chords is Chord Chemistry by Ted Greene.

In short I'll list a few of the more common chord combinations that work and try to give a reasonable explanation.

1. Any major triad can be extended (or even replaced) by a minor chord played on its 3rd.  The combination creates a Maj7 on the original root, example C + Emin = CMaj7, the 5th of Emin is the Maj7 of C.
2. Any major triad can be extended (or replaced) by its relative minor, i.e. a minor chord on the 6th degree of the key to create a 6th chord.  Example, C + Amin = C6.
3. A major chord can be extended using a major triad on the 5th degree to create a Maj9 chord.  Example, C + G = CMaj9.
4. A minor triad can be extended using the relative major to create a minor 7th.  Example, Amin + C = A-7.

For option 3 it is not advisable to use the V7 chord as an extension as that would create a potential conflict with the defining root chord, the I.  The V7 contains the 4th degree of the original chord which is typically an avoid note.  The V7 has a dim 5th interval in it that has a tendency to want to resolve to the I chord.  I + V works as a poly chord but I + V7 no as well (or at all).

Comparing 2 and 4 you will see the exact same pair of chords makes two different chords, C6 and A-7.  The notes of these chords is identical, they are inversions of each other.  In general a chord can be extended with as many notes in or out of key as you like as long as you like the result.  An overarching rule of thumb (not set in stone) is avoid the 4th.  An exception being if you want to hear a suspension.  Rules were meant to be broken.

Using this you can work out possible chord harmonies on your own.  I hope it helps.

Comment: I see this has been down voted without explanation.  The whole point of down voting is to try and point out what's wrong so the answer can be made better.  Why not post what you think is incorrect about the answer.

Comment: More down votes no comments.  I think this is a helpful answer